# Solr Spell checker Filter query

Tags: solr, spell-checking, solr4, solr-schema

I was trying to build spell checker on the top of solr.
The basic information looks good enough http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent#Introduction

Can I somehow limit the scope of spell checker to a specific query.
For e.g I want the spell checker to just correct spelling where
genre=international. (genre is a text field defined in my schema.xml)

**EDIT**

To make the question more precise:
How can I filter query for spell checker component.
fq=genre:music&query=jacksn

Then the spell corrector should look only into the document which have genre:music

Comment: Just found your question, I asked about the same a couple of minutes ago. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to restrict the dictionary building to a single field?
If so you can modify your solrconfig.xml and set the dictionary source to the "genre" field:

```
<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

  <lst name="spellchecker">
    <str name="name">default</str>
    <str name="classname">solr.IndexBasedSpellChecker</str>
    <str name="field">genre</str>
```

EDIT:
So you have multiple countries and you have different products on each country.
It might be more practical to split each country into its own core using a technique called sharding and this way you can configure your modules in each core.

Have a read: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin

Comment: I want to have different spell checker for different countries. How can I do that?